# Управление состояниями вкладок

Tags: c#, winforms

В исходном состоянии у меня есть программа с несколькими вкладками с помощью контейнера `TabControl`
Можно ли использовать группу `CheckBox'ов` для включения,либо выключения определенных вкладок? `CheckBox'ы` в отдельном `GroupBox` , в котором надо будет галочками выбрать состав тепловой схемы(Активность или неактивность некоторых вкладок)

Comment: Конечно можно. Обработчик change есть, вкладки visible менять можно.

Comment: А как это примерно будет выглядеть?Подскажите где можно посмотреть что то подобное или может вы сами напишете?

Comment: @МихаилК мне кажется что Вам необходимо скинуть хотя бы кусок своей реализации чтобы мы её смогли поправить. на ресурсе StackOverFlow никто ни за кого ничего не делает. Вам тут могут объяснить, натолкнуть на мысль, исправить Ваши ошибки. nick_n_a, Вам уже дал исчерпывающий ответ. Напишите логику внутри своих чекбоксов относительно IsChecked.Value. Можете описать своего рода контроллер,который будет вызываться внутри и простукивать каждый чекбокс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Затруднение может возникнуть лишь только с тем, что класс `TabPage` скрывает свое свойство `Enabled`. Поэтому перед тем, как выставить это свойство можете привести объект класса `TabPage` к родительскому классу `Control` и далее обратиться к  этому свойству. Это необходимо делать, если в `TabControl` находится один `TabPage`. В вашем случае, насколько понимаю, вкладок несколько, поэтому смело можете использовать свойство, хоть его и будет скрывать IntelliSense.

Вам нужно повесить по обработчику события `CheckedChanged` на каждый ваш `CheckBox`:

```
    private void CB_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox myCB = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (myCB.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            tabPage.Enabled = true;

        }
        if (myCB.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            tabPage.Enabled = false;

        }
    }
```